# pass var to .load (ajax) php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a php file that loads in the div ajax.
I want to pass the php variable to that loaded php file.

```
        <?
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        ?>

        <script>
        $(function() {
            $("body").click(function(e) {
                if (e.target.id == "contentblock" || $(e.target).parents("#contentblock").size()) {
                        //alert("Inside div");
                        if ($(e.target).is("a")) {
                            $('#afterdownload').fadeIn('slow');
                            $('#ajax').load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/test.php');

                        }
                }
            });
        })   
        </script>

        <div id="ajax"></div>
```

This is how my test.php looks. The test.php loads but when I uncomment the include, which I want to use to pass the variable to this php, it doesn't show anything.

```
    <?
    //include 'single.php';
    ?>

    <p>You downloaded Post: <?php echo $post_id; ?></p>
```

Comment: `$('#ajax').load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/test.php?variablename=value');`

Comment: Then use `<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['variablename']); ?>` in your test.php file.

Comment: so in the first this?

`$('#ajax').load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/test.php?post_id=<? echo $post_id ?>');`

And in the test.php this?

`<?php echo strip_tags($post_id['post_id']); ?>
<p>You downloaded Post: <?php echo $post_id; ?></p> `

This doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $('#ajax').load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/test.php?choices=<?php echo $post_id; ?>');
```

and in php file

```
$_GET['choices']
```

Comment: This makes it so that the php isn't even loaded in the div.

Comment: There was an ; missing
`var value= <?php echo $post_id; ?> ;` This edited makes it load the php file.

But now is the question, how do i use the var in that php file.

is it just likethis?
`$post_id = $_GET['post_id'];`

Comment: i showed it, choices to be passed in the GET, check the edit bro

Comment: ok so now it outputs "You downloaded Post: Array"
using this in test.php
`<?php
$_GET['choices'];
 //echo strip_tags($post_id['post_id']);
?>
<p>You downloaded Post: <?php echo "$_GET"; ?></p> `

Comment: First print_r get variable and see how it is printing the choice. Then get the id

Comment: when i do print_r($_GET); beneath the $_GET['post_id']; it outputs as "array()" so I presume the array is empty.

Comment: when i use 
`$('#ajax').load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/test.php?choices=value');`

Instead of the other one it outputs "Array ( [choices] => value )"

Comment: When i do `echo reset($_GET);` in the test.php

It outputs Value. But how do i get the number out of that?

Comment: $_GET['choices'] do thia. And check if you get the value or not

Comment: Fixed it! the value was always empty.

changed to  `$('#ajax').load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/test.php?choices=<?php echo $post_id; ?>');`

And now it loads my postID!! THX!!